# Insert array elements separately into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

how can i insert each element in the array into a separate column in the database and loop it for each array index ?

for example from array index 0,

- insert 1 in column s1
- insert 3 in column s2
- insert 5 in column s3
- insert 11 in column s4

format of array i have now

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 13
        )
)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple foreach loop you can achieve the insertion-

```
foreach($your_arr as $val){    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (s1, s2, s3, s4) VALUES ('$val[0]', '$val[1]', '$val[2]', '$val[3]')";
    mysqli_query($your_db_conn, $sql);
}
```

I hope this will help you.